# Differentiability with multiple variables

Tags: differential-geometry

In my books talking about Lie groups, it is written that a Lie group is a manifold with a group structure. And it is said that the $*$ and the $.^-1$ (the inverse) maps must be differentiables.

For the inverse law no problem, but what does that precisely mean for the $*$ law.

Indeed we have a map $* :G ~ * ~  G\rightarrow G$.

A map from $f : G\rightarrow G$ will be differentiable if, 
$$\phi \circ f \circ \psi^-1 : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$$
 is differentiable (where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the chart maps).

But as the map $*$ has a cartesian product as input does that mean that :

$$\forall g_1 ~  *_{g_1} : g \rightarrow g_1*g $$
$$\forall g_2 ~  *^{g_2} : g \rightarrow g*g_2 $$

must both be differentiable ?

Is that the definition of differentiability for two variables map on manifolds ?

Comment: Your map goes from $G\times G$ to $G$, and you can define a structure of (smooth) manifold on $G\times G$ by taking any couple of charts $(\phi,U)$, $(\psi,V)$ and defining $\phi\times\psi:U\times V\to G\times G$ with $\phi\times\psi(u,v)=(\phi(u),\psi(v))$ ?

Comment: Hmmmm ok so I need to use a cartesian products of chart to answer the question. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.